# Select node based on its second class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with each row first given a class odd or even.

I also give one row in the table a "row_selected" class.

How do I select the row with the class "row_selected" with jquery?

I tried even the most general $('.row_selected') and that doesn't even work

Comment: That should work ... 

1 - make sure your executing your code at the right ***time***

2 - make sure the class is there when your code executes

Comment: Yeah you're right, I passed the function in the wrong way

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you do not have two class attributes. You want to have multiple classes in one attribute separated by spaces:

```
<tr class="odd row_selected">
```

**Not**:

```
<tr class="odd" class="row_selected">
```

Then you can select with all of:

```
$('.odd')              // Has class odd
$('.row_selected')     // Has class row_selected
$('.odd.row_selected') // Has both
$('.row_selected.odd') // Has both
```